# Update excel cell from sharepoint column

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, excel, 2019

I know it is possible to define on an excel file some custom properties. And this properties can take the value from a determined excel cell.

With this properties created, in a document library you can create columns with the same name as the custom properties. Then when uploading this excel file to SharePoint, this SharePoint columns automatically get the value defined in the custom properties.

So at the end, the SharePoint column gets the value reflected on the excel cell at the moment the document was uploaded.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-cell-values-as-a-custom-excel-file-property-to-help-manage-your-workbooks-in-a-sharepoint-library-e0f0658a-76dd-4c6a-97d4-8e20e3744ec2

What I don't know, is if this behavior can be configured somehow bidirectional, this means, after uploading the excel file to SharePoint, if I edit the value of the SharePoint columns, the change gets reflected in the excel cell or on the custom property.

There is anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It will not be updated automatically, you could check this UserVoice:
[Support custom property in Excel for the web](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42717215-support-custom-property-in-excel-for-the-web)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any valid alternative to modify then the cell value from content set in the library columns?